# cp1250 encoded source code on Eclipse/Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, encoding

How to setup your environment to work with cp1250 source code in Eclipse on Linux?

(I know, if you can use UTF-8, unfortunately, it's not always possible)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990711/eclipse-charset-for-working-with-windows-linux-on-same-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Text file encoding**

Go to:

Windows > Preferences > General > Workspace

than find:

Text file encoding > Other

and just type in manually the encoding: cp1250

You probably want to change as well the "New text file line delimiter" to Other > Windows.

[source](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/351092/)

**Maven**

To build the code you need to pass set `-encoding` argument on javac, to do this in maven add this to your `.bashrc`

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=CP1250"
```